# Is Excel's FALSE like infinity?

Tags: excel

Why does `=FALSE<10000000000` evaluate as `FALSE` and `=FALSE>10000000000` evaluate as `TRUE`? I have tried some different numbers and this seems to always be the case.

Comment: More accurately, it would appear that `False = Nothing` in Excel. `True > Nothing` and `Nothing > Any value`. The problem is that True and False are not numerical values, they are functions returning logical values which are treated differently. I haven't been able to find any official documentation on how logical values are handled though.

Comment: You can actually see the same behavior with `TRUE` as well. My best guess is that since you are dealing with two inherently different types (boolean and numeric), your results won't be as you expect. For instance, `FALSE=0` returns `FALSE`, despite 0 being the numeric representation. Like @DanielCook I'm having a hard time finding documentation on the underlying internals, but my best guess is that the type itself makes equality comparisons useless (great question, by the way :) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design.  Search help for "Troubleshoot Sort" to see the default sort order.

> In an ascending sort, Microsoft Excel uses the following order.
>
> Numbers: Numbers are sorted from the smallest negative number to the largest positive number.
>
> Alphanumeric sort: When you sort alphanumeric text, Excel sorts left to right, character by character. For example, if a cell contains the text "A100," Excel places the cell after a cell that contains the entry "A1" and before a cell that contains the entry "A11."
>
> Text and text that includes numbers are sorted in the following order:
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (space) ! " # $ % & ( ) * , . / : ; ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~ + < = > A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> Apostrophes (') and hyphens (-) are ignored, with one exception: If two text strings are the same except for a hyphen, the text with the hyphen is sorted last.
>
> Logical values: In logical values, FALSE is placed before TRUE.
>
> Error values: All error values are equal.
>
> Blanks: Blanks are always placed last.

The default sort order matters because that is how Excel was designed to compare different data types.  Logical values are always after text and numbers.  Error values are always after that.  Blanks are always last.  When you use comparison operators (<, <=, =, etc.) it uses the same comparison algorithm as the sort (or more likely, the sort alogrithm uses the comparison operator code, which makes them identical).

`TRUE<>1` according to the sort order, but `--TRUE=1`.  The formula parser recognized that you're trying to negate something.  If it's a Boolean value, it converts it to 0 or 1.  There's nothing 0-ish or 1-ish about the Boolean value, it's just the result of an internal Type Coercion function.  If you type `--"SomeString"` it does the same thing.  It sends the string into the Type Coercion function that reports back 'Unable to coerce' and ends up as #VALUE! in the cell.

That's the 'Why it behaves that way' answer.  I don't know the 'Why did they design it that way' answer.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the boolean TRUE/FALSE are different data types to numbers. Check this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687869.aspx) to see that boolean variables are stored in 2-byte (or whatever a short integer is for a certain architecture). However this is the memory where the data is stored, because excel actually has a special data class for boolean vars. Specifically: xltypeNum for numbers, xltypeStr for strings, and xltypeBool for what we discuss.

The relations between same types is clear, now what TRUE<1000 does?? probably nothing meaningful-useful.

Ways to overcome this issue:

```
=ABS(BOOLEAN_VAR), i.e.  =ABS(FALSE) --> 0 and =ABS(TRUE)  --> 1
```

or

```
=INT(BOOLEAN_VAR), i.e.  =INT(FALSE) --> 0 and =INT(TRUE)  --> 1
```

or

```
=BOOLEAN_VAR*1,  i.e.  =FALSE*1 --> 0 and =TRUE*1  --> 1
```

or

```
=+BOOLEAN_VAR,  i.e.  =+FALSE --> 0 and =+TRUE  --> 1
```

As you see in these ways you force excel to output a numeric type of data, either by providing the boolean into a function or using the boolean var in an expression.

Comment: But... `True=1` is false and `False=0` is also false. This sort of feels like not an answer. I'm not saying I can give a better one though.